# How do I use generics in Apache Arrow?

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

Say I have a function called `boop`. It has different behaviour depending on the class of its argument, so I use generics, like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c("these", "are", "some", "strings"),
                 b = 1:4)

boop <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("boop", x)

boop.numeric <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)

boop.character <- function(x) mean(nchar(x), na.rm =TRUE)

df %>% summarise(across(everything(), boop))
                                
#      a   b
# 1 4.75 2.5
```

Perfect! Now, say I want to use `boop` with a parquet file **before** `collect`ing the data. I can write similar `dplyr` code to above for the `summarise`, but first I need to register my functions. For example,

```r
library(arrow)

register_scalar_function(
  "boop.numeric",
  function(context, x) {
    mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  },
  in_type = schema(x = float64()),
  out_type = float64(),
  auto_convert = TRUE
)
```

But how do I first of all define `boop` as a generic? If I translate my original `boop` directly into an `arrow` format I need to define the input schema. Nevertheless, unlike `boop.numeric` or `boop.character`, its generic so `x` doesn't have a class.

---

**Question:** How do I use generics, such as shown above, with Apache Arrow prior to `collect`ing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that this is currently possible.

I'm currently working on [a PR which enables the use of `where()`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/14371) which I hope to have done for the upcoming release (end of the month).  Using this in conjunction with `across()`, the PR for which is now merged, would allow you to manually specify `df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), boop.numeric))` etc, as a workaround.

I've also opened [a ticket on the project JIRA requesting implementation of the ability to call user-defined generic functions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-17948).